# Your experience with the "soft - yet - wheeled" type of checked luggage?

Tags: luggage, damaged-luggage

I have to take a few long flights so I thought I would try the  "soft - yet - wheeled" type as checked luggage.

[image]

That one is "small suitcase" sized.

"Large suitcase sized" S.Y.W. luggage also seems generally available these days [example](https://www.eddiebauer.com/p/82300256/expedition-34-duffel-2.0)

I was just wondering if anyone here has used this type of checked luggage ever or often?

It seems to combine the worst possible damage risks, ie ripped open, unprotected easily-bustable handle/wheels, and no security (other than the 50 cent separate zip lock you have to buy). On the other hand, it's very light.

I was just looking for the experience of others with this, TY

Comment: If it's not full, that can cause problems. I have one which comes with built in straps and I've used a separate strap on a different duffel-style bag.

Answer (score 2):

1. These work generally fine.
2. One of these lasts me between 250,000 to 500,000 miles (flown)
3. The thing that breaks first is either handles or wheels
4. Locking is a non-issue since you can't lock because of security. I never lock at all and nothing was ever stolen from me.
5. Nothing ever broke inside the bag but I generally don't take fragile stuff and if I do I just wrap some clothing around it.
6. There is no single large flat surface so stuff tend to gets wrinkled a bit.
7. If you plan to carry on, watch the weight. European and Asian airlines are far more restrictive than US ones

Comment: smiley, heh great answer thanks.  Love point 2 :)   You know, fwiw I just got one of those ridiculous "small, 'wire', combo" locks you put through the two zip knobs (natch with TSA hole).  It's intriguing that the one i got (pic) has the $5 "wheels + handle, 't-shaped part'" **simply glued on** to the crappy canvas bag. Hence, it's very light. However, I notice they stopped making that model and replaced it with one which has a very firm plastic "base", to which the wheels/handle/T is fully attached (hence, the new model is pointless, heavier than a solid wheeled).

Comment: Yes, for anyone googling, one can only have a tiny carry on, on basically non-US airlines. This would not work as carry on, other than on united etc and "if you're lucky"

Comment: @Fattie Any "TSA" lock only protects against accidental opening during handling, they provide exactly zero security (less than a zip tie). Anyone willing to risk their job by stealing stuff will have the widely available $2 set of TSA keys handy.

Comment: @TooTea yes, I'm aware of that  :)  the bag in the pic doesn't have any sort of "zip knobs tie" thing, so I just bought a ridiculous "tsa zip lock" - exactly as you say, the only real value is prevent accidental opening